# Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract a frame from a video in stdin given a specific time.
FFMPEG recommends the usage of `-ss` param before input to avoid input decode.

The given command works:
`ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:01 -i sample.mp4 -f image2 -frames:v 1 output.png`

Changing the input to stdin, it do not works:
`cat sample.mp4 | ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:01 -i pipe: -f image2 -frames:v 1 output.png`

The output is:

```
Output #0, image2, to 'out.png':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

But, if I place the `-ss` after the `-i pipe:`, it works. However, processing became extremely slow for very long videos:

`cat sample.mp4 | ffmpeg -y -i pipe: -ss 00:00:01 -f image2 -frames:v 1 output.png`

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `-ss` before the input then ffmpeg will search for specific timestamp in the input file (it works "instantly"). When you are using `-ss` after the input / before the output then ffmpeg will search for specific timestamp in the output file (that is why it is slower as ffmpeg will encode the input file till the selected timestamp).

When you are using `-ss` before the input and the input is a pipe then it is a little complicated: it seems ffmpeg does not like small values of `-ss` parameter in that case (like your `-ss 00:00:01`) but any other more further value (like `-ss 00:01:00` or even `-ss 00:00:02`) work for me.

Comment: But, it's a bug of FFmpeg? It is very strange to me.

Comment: @RodrigoBrito: What's strange, which sentence?

Comment: This sentence: "seems ffmpeg does not like small values". It works with input file, but do not works with stdin.

Comment: @RodrigoBrito: I'm not sure if it's a bug. Pipe works differently than direct input file, maybe it just needs more data to decide "what to do".

Comment: @RodrigoBrito: The general solution would be: use `-ss` before the input. If you need the frame from the very beginning of the video then use `-ss` after the input (and in this case you won't need to wait too long as the frame is at the start).